# jQuery grab specific img src folder name

Tags: jquery

So my img src generates like this `img/0001/name0001/img0001.jpg` and im trying to grab `/name0001/` only any idea ? thanks!

my code:

```
var parent = $('.img');
    $(parent, document).click(function() {

        var dirz = this.src;
            var dirb = dirz.split('/')[2];
            alert(dirb);
});
```

it alerts with blank?

Comment: $(img).attr("src").split("/")[2]

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili you should submit that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: yes you are right but that was shorter than posting as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file names are all in that format,

```
var dir = filename.split('/')[2];
```

Note that if you use the `.src` *property* of the image then it will include the full URL, including the scheme and hostname, which is not the same as the input shown in the question.

To parse the path as supplied in the HTML, you need to read the *attribute* using `.attr('src')`

Comment: @Musa true, but any noob ought to be able to figure out how to add those back in, if they're really required.

Comment: i tried like this but nothing shows up any idea ? var dirz = this.src;
   var dirb = dirz.split('/')[2];
   alert(dirb);

Comment: looks OK - did the alert even appear?

Comment: Try `alert(this)` and report back...   If `this` is an image object then I presume you must be within an event handler attached to said image?

Comment: alerts this [object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: ah - you're reading `.src` which is a fully expanded (file: ?) URL, not `.attr('src')` which contains the path as specified in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
var src = 'img/0001/name0001/img0001.jpg';

var items = src.split('/')[2]  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting on `/` and grabbing the corresponding segment?

```
var src = "img/0001/name0001/img0001.jpg",
    segment = src.split('/')[2]; // "name0001"
```

Answer (score 0):

use the split method:

```
str = "img/0001/name0001/img0001.jpg";    
var n=str.split("/");
```

then just grab n[2]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
var src = "img/0001/name0001/img0001.jpg",
segment = src.split('/')[2]; // "name0001"
```

Thanks